# Problems with camera2 on the Galaxy S5

Tags: android, camera2, samsung-galaxy

I'm trying to analyse cameraimages while filming. 
This is running on most of the devices. 
I'm using the camera2 API.

But the preview freezes if I start recording on my galaxy S5.
Does anybody know how to avoid this on galaxy devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the only way you can avoid this, is to switch to the camera API. Samsung Devices haven't implemented the new camera2 API until now. I also tried to make a Augmented Reality APP with the camera2 API and tested with my Samsung Device, but unfortunately, the most features and configurations of the camera2 API are not supported on Samsung Galaxy S5. 
So: Either you use another Hardware for your Applikation, or you go back to camera(1)API

Answer (score 0):

You are right , me too faced this issue once but i found solution for this
[Samsung camera (galaxy series)](http://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/camera) use only  if you need to implement Camera 2 API or else you can use older Camera API for wide support.